# Question about using jquery tooltipster plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tooltip

I'm using tooltipster to show some data. (using jquery, tooltipster)

Below is my code.

```
<html>
<header>
<style>
#tooltip_content{display: none;}
</style>
</header>
<body>
<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content">This span has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!</span>

  <div id="tooltip_content">
    <div>
      <img src="../static/images/caticon.png" /> 
    </div>
      <strong>This is the content of my tooltip!</strong>
  </div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
      content: $('#tooltip_content').html()
    });
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run the code, html code is printed in tooltip.
[image]

IS there a solution to print my code to html?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I have to use **contentAsHTML: true**